# How do I use multiple images in android programming?

Tags: java, android, xml, graphics

For about two months I've been assigned the task of programming a game, specifically a card game called Pazzak from the game, Knights of The Old Republic. I have an understanding of programming and I have taken a few classes. The problem lies with android programming.

The game runs like blackjack but the player can modify the total with cards that add or subtract an amount to the total. For example: The player is given a 5, then the opponent gets a 10. Then the player gets a 10. The player can then play a +5 card on their turn to reach 20, the number you want to reach. If the opponent were to go over, say 22, they could play a -2 card to reach 20.

**The problem is**, I am having trouble displaying an image in the background and then displaying an image on top of that one. I can get one image to show up but then none on top of it. I've been researching this matter for the duration of the 2 months but to no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use some graphic engine for your game. For example AndEngine, it's very easy and simple to learn engine. It will be easy to create game like you want with it. Check http://www.andengine.org/